# How do I export CSV files using iteration?

Tags: r

I need to generate dozens of matrices and export them as individual files. My difficulty is generating the path in the write.csv() function.

I tried creating the entire write.csv as a string, but then I don't know how to turn it from a string back into a function. I tried generating just the path as a string, but when I iterate the path into write.csv() it returns with " " around the edges that screws up the function. Here is my code in its current state.

```
for (i in 1:20)
{
  for (j in 1:2)
  {
    name = paste("Tie",i, "Direction", j, sep ="")
    dummy = cumMatrixSTSD(i,j)

    ###print

    path = paste("'C:\\Users\\WChance\\Desktop\\Shop scans shortcut\\Raw Data\\Error estimation\\",
                 name,
                 ".csv'",
                 sep = ""
                 )
    write.csv(get(name), path, row.names = TRUE)
  }
```

"cumMatrix(i,j)" is my function that generates the dozens of matrices that I need for individual export. I tested the path and it works when it is in the form

> 'C:\Users\WChance\Desktop\Shop scans shortcut\Raw Data\Error estimation\Tie1Direction1.csv'

where "Tie1Direction1" is the name of one of my matrices. There is no problem with the "get(name)" or "row.names" arguments either.

Comment: 1) Isn't it `get(dummy)` instead? 2) **Remove the single quotes** in `paste("'C:\\Users etc` and `.csv'"`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I'm not even understanding why one would need to use `get` here.

Comment: @Dason Right, I was following the OP without thinking.

Comment: @Dason: maybe cumMatrixSTSD doesn't return the results, but instead directly modifies the parent frame ;-)

Comment: "name" is just  a string. "dummy = cumMatrixSTSD(i,j)" generates the matrix. "assign(name,dummy)" assigns the name to the matrix that I generate. get(name) calls that matrix. I suppose that it would work just fine if I used "dummy" in place of "get(name)"

Comment: Okay, removing the quotes worked, thank you

Comment: For constructing file paths, see the `file.path` function

Comment: @chance.will your code doesn't have any assign statement in it. I'm assuming you reduced it down to what you thought was minimal representation but I can't know if code that I don't see.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. It's in the actual version. I forgot that I took it out